# line integral in vector field over parameterized line curve... direction of parameterization correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm having some trouble locating the sign error in my line integral calculation for Work done in an electrostatic field.  The textbook indicates that my work should be negative, as in $-400~\mu J$, but my answer is $400~ \mu J$.  Mostly, i'm confused if I parameterized the direction of the line integral correctly and set the limited correcting in the line integral.

---

Here's my work:

Given electrostatic field: $\vec{E}=(x/2+2y)~\hat{x} + 2x~\hat{y}~~~(V/m)$

And a test charge $Q = -20 \mu C$ moving in the eletrostatic field from:

(4,2,0) meters to (0,0,0) meters

Here's a plot of the vector field E:

[image: vector field]

---

First I find the parametric line equation:

$\vec{r}(t) = (-4t+4)\hat{x} + (2t+2)\hat{y}$

and its derivative is:

$\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = -4\hat{x} + 2 \hat{y}$

---

testing out the line equation I find that:

$\vec{r}(t=0) = 4\hat{x} + 2\hat{y} + 0\hat{z}$

$\vec{r}(t=1) = 0\hat{x} + 0\hat{y} + 0\hat{z}$

which matches the coordinates (4,2,0) to (0,0,0) specified in the problem...

---

then, i setup the line integral for work, assuming Q is a positive test charge that is moving against the Electric Field and work should be positive:

$W = Q \int^1_0 \vec{E}\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big) \bullet \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}~dt$

However, Q is not a positive test charge...but the assumption is that the negative sign of the test charge will correct the orientation as long as I set the problem up for a positive test charge...

---

substituting $\vec{r}(t)$ into $\vec{E}$:

$\vec{E}\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big) = \bigg[\frac{-4t+4}{2} + 2(2t+2) \bigg] \hat{x} + \bigg[2(-4t + 4)\bigg]\hat{y}$

$\vec{E}\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big) = (2t+6)\hat{x} + (-8t+8)\hat{y}$

---

$\vec{E}\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big) \bullet \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = -24t -8$

---

finally i can perform the line integral:

$W = (-20\mu) \int \limits_0^1 (-24t -8) dt$

$W = (-20\mu) \bigg[ -12t -8t \bigg]^{1}_{0}$

$W = (-20\mu) (-12 -8)$

$W = (-20\mu)(-20)$

$\boxed{W = 400~ \mu J}$

(Which is the wrong answer... its suppose to be -400 $\mu J$ )

Its -400 so that when I add in the work done by two other paths that are part of a closed loop... it adds to zero:

(0,0,0)->(4,0,0) => $80 \mu J$

(4,0,0)->(4,2,0) => $320 \mu J$

thus: 80 + 320 - 400 = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametric equation is wrong. At $t = 1$, we get 
\begin{align}
\vec{r}(1) 
&= (-4\cdot1+4)\hat{x} + (2\cdot2+2)\hat{y}\\
&= 0\hat{x} + 4\hat{y}
\end{align}

It SHOULD be 
$$
\vec{r}(t) = (-4t+4)\hat{x} + (-2t+2)\hat{y}
$$
with derivative
$$
\vec{r'}(t) = -4\hat{x} - 2\hat{y}.
$$

Comment: Thanks... just tried it and it fixes the sign... it now comes out to $-400 \mu J$ as expected... I was just getting confused because it strangely  came out to $+400 \mu J$ with the wrong line equation... was making me worry that I didn't understand the order of integral limits and the orientation of the vector field...

Comment: Sometimes we have bad luck, and a wrong answer is not only wrong, but misleading. :(